# Jquery User Dialog Button

Tags: jquery, html

I have this Jquery User Dialog:

```
    <!-- jQuery UI dialogs -->
    <div class="widget">    
        <div class="head"><h5 class="iAlert">jQuery UI dialogs</h5></div>
        <div class="body aligncenter">

            <div class="uDialog">
                <div id="dialog-message" title="Download complete">
                    <p><img src="images/icons/color/tick.png" alt="" class="icon" />Your files have downloaded successfully into the My Downloads folder.</p>
                    <p>Currently using <strong>36% of your storage space</strong></p>

                    <div class="uiForm">
                        <form action=""  class="mainForm">
                            <input type="text" value="http://" name="inputtext"/>
                            <input type="radio" name="question1" checked="checked" /><label>Selected radio</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="question1" /><label>Normal state</label>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Sample page content to illustrate the layering of the dialog -->
                <input type="button" value="Usual jQuery UI dialog" class="blueBtn" id="opener" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm like to change input from button to image, like this:

```
<a href="#" title=""class="btn55 mr10"><img src="images/add.png" alt="" /><span>Add</span></a>
```

There is a way?

Comment: you want to customize the input button to have image instead?

Answer (score 0):

can you create a fiddle, so i can be more precise?
here is a link [jsfiddle.net/trajce/yhQeZ/](http://jsfiddle.net/trajce/yhQeZ/)
For the input you can do it like this:

```
/* this is general selector, if you want to target specific element, then add class or id*/
    input[type="button"]
    {
        width:120px;/*these are just some sample width and height*/
        height:30px;
        background: url('http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png') center no-repeat;/*set your image as background of the input.*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Example in a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FnDht/)

Using the class of the input

```
.blueBtn {
    background-image: url('http://www.psdgraphics.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/push-button.jpg');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 40px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Or with the background rules combined

```
.blueBtn {
    background: url('http://www.psdgraphics.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/push-button.jpg')no-repeat center;
    background-size: 100% 100% ;
    height: 40px;
    width: 50px;
}
```